# TypeError: exphbs is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-handlebars

I am trying to use the express-handlebars module but have an error.
My code:

```
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');

app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({ extname: '.hbs', defaultLayout: "main"}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
```

My error:

```
"app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({ extname: '.hbs', defaultLayout: "main"}));
                   ^

TypeError: exphbs is not a function"
```

I can't seem to figure it out why is it not working properly.
Any ideas?

Comment: import {engine} instead of exphbs

Answer (score 58):

You should use "exphbs.engine" instead of "exphbs".

```
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs.engine({ extname: '.hbs', defaultLayout: "main"}));
```

Comment: this worked for me as well, but I wonder if somebody who knows would be so kind as to further explain the reasoning? I seems like 'engine' is a method of the object exported by require('express-handlebars')? If so, does destructuring with an import ( ie import { engine} = ... ) achieve the same effective result? All the tutorials I've seen do not include the engine method in their examples

Comment: That works. I wonder how you knew that?

Answer (score 18):

**You have two options to solve this**

**1st Method-**

In this you just have to update a single word **.enigne**

Change this:

```
 app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({ extname: '.hbs', defaultLayout: "main"}));
```

To

```
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs.engine({ extname: '.hbs', defaultLayout: "main"}));
```

**2nd Method-**

In this, you have to update

```
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
```

To

```
 const { engine } = require('express-handlebars');
```

And

```
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({ extname: '.hbs', defaultLayout: "main"}));
```

To

```
app.engine('handlebars', engine({ extname: '.hbs', defaultLayout: "main"}));
```

Goodluck

Answer (score 8):

If you want to use `express-handlebars` with [commonJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CommonJS) module you should import it like that:

```js
const express = require('express');
const { engine } = require('express-handlebars');

const app = express();

app.engine('handlebars', engine({ extname: '.hbs', defaultLayout: "main"}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.set("views", "./views");

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('home');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

If you want to go with [ES6 module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015), you can follow the official [readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars)

Answer (score 7):

```
"app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({ extname: '.hbs', defaultLayout: "main"}));
                   ^
TypeError: exphbs is not a function"
```

This error can be resolved by adding a `engine() function` to the `exphbs` constant, OR, just calling the `engine()` function.

`exphbs.engine()`, because `exphbs` is a constant not a function, we have to call the `engine()` function from the `express-handlebars` package, so that we can use the handlebars templating engine!

##### [express-handlebars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars) usage guide

---

You may get a second error if you are not using a Layout (`main.handlebars`/ `main.hbs`) file.
If someone is having trouble with the `main.handlebars`/ `main.hbs` file error.
You can set the `defaultLayout` as `null`.

Something like this:

```js
const expressHbs = require('express-handlebars');

app.engine('handlebars', expressHbs.engine({
    layoutsDir: 'views/layouts/',
    defaultLayout: null,
    extname: 'handlebars'
  })
);

app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.set('views', 'views');    // optional
```

> `layoutsDir` is the location of your layouts (if there is any - this can be omitted if you are not using a layout).
> `extname` (extension name) depends upon the choice of the user!

Answer (score 4):

that's right, per documentation from [hbs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars), this option will get the job done.

```
import express from 'express';
import { engine } from 'express-handlebars';

const app = express();

app.engine('.hbs', engine({extname: '.hbs'}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
app.set('views', './views');
```

Answer (score 4):

Use it like this as per the [express-handlebars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars) documentation

```
const expressHbs = require('express-handlebars');

app.engine('handlebars', expressHbs.engine({
    layoutsDir: 'views/', // directory to handlebars files
    defaultLayout: null,
    extname: 'handlebars'
  })
);

app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.set('views', 'views');    // optional
```

Answer (score 3):

1. var exphbs = require("express-handlebars");
2. app.engine("handlebars",exphbs({ defaultLayout: "main" }));

Replace with this :

1. *const { engine } = require("express-handlebars");*
2. *app.engine("handlebars", engine({ defaultLayout: "main" }));*

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain why the changes solves the problem

Answer (score 2):

```js
const { engine } = require('express-handlebars');
```

and

```js
app.engine('handlebars', engine({ extname: '.hbs', defaultLayout: "main"}));
```